# Hide questions with ignored tags, like StackOverflow

Tags: feature-request

I don't like them being whited out, so I still have to scroll through them. Would be nice if those questions were hidden, like StactOverflow does. What do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the preferences of your profile:

[image]

You must have set this on SO and not on SF. It's a per-site preference.

Comment: It did not work at first. So I waited for couple hours - the list of ignored tags got updated (it was empty), and the checkbox worked (but I had to check it again.